# Android Google Maps API not working with debug.keystore

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am attempting to create a MapView application following the tutorial from the Android website [**here**](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html). I have got everything set up and the map displays but with empty tiles!

The API key I'm using is generated from the debug.keystore located in *"C:\Users\Pete\.android"* and all of the correct permissions are set up in the manifest. The maps library is also in the manifest but it still doesn't work. I have tried creating a new debug keystore and placed it in the same folder (obviously also generating a new API key) and still no luck.

**(30/05/2011) Edit:**

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.stringerapps.testing.gps"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0">
   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

   <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Home"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
             </intent-filter>
        </activity>

     <!-- import the library com.google.android.maps!!! -->
     <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

     <!-- permissions -->
     <uses-permission
         android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
     </uses-permission>
     <uses-permission
         android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION">
     </uses-permission>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="api-key-here-omitted"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Home.xml**

```
package com.stringerapps.testing.gps;

import java.util.List;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class Home extends MapActivity {

LinearLayout linearLayout;
MapView mapView;

List<Overlay> mapOverlays;
Drawable drawable;
MyItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.androidmarker);
    itemizedOverlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(drawable);

    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(19240000, -99120000);
    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "", "");

    GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint(35410000, 139460000);
    OverlayItem overlayitem2 = new OverlayItem(point2, "", "");

    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem2);
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: what's the error you're getting when you try to start the app?

Comment: Sorry if this is dumb, but have why can't you generate your own API key for use with your Google Account?

Comment: Actually, if I remember, I think the example docs had malformed xml. I would double-check and ensure your manifest files are well-formed.

Comment: @wajiw No errors, the app starts fine but only displays blank map tiles

@Alan As far as I know the manifest is all good, edited to include.

Comment: can you show your activity code and the xml for your layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your manifest file needs some reshuffling:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.stringerapps.testing.gps"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0">
   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

     <!-- permissions -->
     <uses-permission
         android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
     </uses-permission>
     <uses-permission
         android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION">
     </uses-permission>
   <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Home"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
             </intent-filter>
        </activity>

     <!-- import the library com.google.android.maps!!! -->
     <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />


    </application>
</manifest>
```

Try that and I'll look through your other files to see if I can find anything else.

Comment: @Peter you need to have the uses-permission nodes placed as a children of <manifest ...>

Answer (score 3):

The `<uses-permission>` tags need to go outside of the `<application>` tag.

See: [Google map displaying only blank tiles android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763789/google-map-displaying-only-blank-tiles-android)

Answer (score 1):

Important thing here is always to use proper fingerprint (keystore for fingerprint). I had the same problem before:). If you are debugging your application, use debug fingerprint as is [described here](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-google-map-application-example) and you will be safe. Then if you will decide to publish application then you will create own fingerprint for public use.