# Android MapActivity: not being displayed

Tags: java, android, google-maps, dictionary

I've searched all the other threads and followed the official guide, but I still can't display a map on my android device.

I've generated the md5 fingerprint, uploaded it to google, copied the key into my show_map.xml file, enabled INTERNET permissions, etc. and it still won't work!

I've even tried with Android 2.1 instead of 2.2 (which I'm currently using).

Here's my show_map.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <com.google.android.maps.MapView
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:apiKey="04IbV5zNab7z_PHdxydzY-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
       />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here's my Manifest file:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity android:name=".Clarity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".main_menu"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".ShowJobsOnMap"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>

    </application>
```

Any help anyone can offer is greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: Did you sign the application with the correct key?

Comment: I don't know... I think it's the correct key. It's called debug.keystore.

Comment: I'm referring to the last step described [here](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-overview.html#sign)

Comment: I'm using the debug certificate. How do I sign my app? I presume this is different to exporting a signed application?

Comment: In eclipse right click on project -> Android Tools -> Export Signed Application Package. 
For development purposes you should generate a second api key, that works with your debug certificate.

Comment: Hi, I did that and it still doesn't work... I'm really stuck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a night's sleep, I figured it out...

[Google map displaying only blank tiles android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763789/google-map-displaying-only-blank-tiles-android)

`<uses-permission ...>` must be a child of `<manifest>`, not `<application>`

*Bangs head off desk*

Thanks for the responses guys