# Updated an app with v1 map in google play now showing blank tiles

Tags: android, google-maps

My application is already in google play with map v1. Now i fixed a bug unrelated to map and tried to update the version in google play. Downloaded new version from google play and found maps are showing blank tiles.

I used right certificate as my version update is success with google play. I used the same map api key, as i unzipped the apk and compared the keys found in few xmls in layout folder between previous and new version.

Google says, that existing v1 keys will continue to work.

What could be the problem? Can someone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you not forget to switch the API key between testing (key signed with your debug certificate) and exporting the app (signed with the release certificate)?

Comment: Other people seem to report that this may come from a modification of your permissions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763789/google-map-displaying-only-blank-tiles-android?rq=1

Comment: @etienne, those are fine in the app version that i published that time.

Answer (score 2):

I recently (2 weeks ago) updated an app that uses android maps v1 api and had no problems. Probably you have messed up something in your code.

1. While developing your app, did it work with the developer's map key?
2. Did you make any changes in the google api console?
3. Did you try switching to the old apk?
4. Did you try rolling back your changes and redeploy?

Comment: 1. Yes, 2. No, 3. How to do that? Is it possible to use exact old apk and publish as version rollback? 4. Yes, didn't work.

Comment: @Galaxy On Publish page where you upload new APK look for the option to roll back to old APK.

Comment: Good to know that rollback feature. As my client doesn't like to rollback, Chosen to upgrade to v2, published and map is working now. Why v1 failed still remains a mystery, which i thought to figure out through this thread. Thanks for sharing these options.

Answer (score 0):

I have dealt with google maps API v1 and I changed over to API V2 recently. I suspect your SDK could have got updated and messed up somewhere. Does your files have package imports look like

"com.google.amdroid.gms.maps.* " or "com.google.android.maps.* " ? I guess you may want to make sure of that. The former is V2 and the latter is V1.

Also try No.3 ,from above answer you will know if your API key is still working or not in the release version.

Answer (score 0):

I would offer you a different checklist:

1. Ensure the apk uploaded to Google Play is signed with the same key as before (unsigned apps will stop the maps from working)
2. Ensure that the API key is set to the live one and not the development one.  Personally I normally have both in my layout.xml file and then just comment out the one I don't need

Comment: Thanks. As you can see the publish is success that indicates my signing has to be correct. To avoid any assumptions, i unzipped the apk itself and verified that the API key is same API key that worked in the past in production.

Comment: Did the package change?  Did the permissions in the manifest change?  (specifically the removal of internet permission).  Anything in logcat regarding this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Bro, Since 18 March, 2013 Google Maps api v1 has been deprecated. So you have to update your app with new Google api v2 version. For Google Map Api v2, visit the following link
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Answer (score -4):

**Step for Making Google Map API Version 2**

1)Creating the SHA-1 for your signature key.

The Eclipse debug key for signing your application can be found in the userhome/.android/debug.keystore file. 
eg) C:\Users\nil pc43.android\debug.keystore

```
    ----->  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\bin\keytool.exe -v -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\Info 1234\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass     
android -keypass android


    Example)
        C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\bin>keytool.exe -v -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "c:\Users\nil pc43\.android\deb
        ug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android
        Alias name: androiddebugkey
        Creation date: Apr 4, 2013
        Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
        Certificate chain length: 1
        Certificate[1]:
        Owner: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
        Issuer: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
        Serial number: 4a5b5c6d
                Valid from: Thu Apr 04 18:33:13 IST 2013 until: Sat Mar 28 18:33:13 IST 2043
        Certificate fingerprints:
                 MD5:  51:CE:5C:07:05:31:98:6A:D5:7C:24:B1:B3:EC:22:A3
                 SHA1: B2:68:A7:D6:3A:FC:8F:15:8D:3E:1F:4A:E8:99:CE:8D:F5:28:07:4D
                 SHA256: 5B:5B:FE:7B:92:7F:06:53:1E:28:BB:D0:E5:CB:05:46:B0:81:76:CC:61:87:97:FA:19:68:B6:C1:08:E8:D6:D9
                 Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
                 Version: 3
```

**2)Register with the Google APIs Console**

```
-----> https://code.google.com/apis/console/
     ----> Go to Services 
Then Activate(ON) the Google Maps Android API v2.
```

**3)Create key for your application**

```
-----> sELECT  API ACCESS
    **You need later to register your application via its package in this console together
    with the SHA-1 fingerprint of your signature key. For this you  select the entry and
    click on the API Access entry. Afterwards click on the Create new Android key...entry.**

-----> Click on "Create New Android KEY"
-----> Enter your SHA-1 fingerprint and the package of your application separated by a semicolon. 

       For example you can use the com.example.mymaps package. (your SHA-1 key;package Name)
```

**4)Change Your Manifist.xml and JAVA File according below link**

```
-----> please Reffer this Link
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html
```

**5)Now Create new KeyStore File and APK file For your project.**

```
----->C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\bin>keytool -list -alias "your alias name" -keystore  "path that have keystor file of yor application"
    Enter keystore password: <pasword of your keystore>
    mapExample, Apr 18, 2013, PrivateKeyEntry,
    Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 71:EF:B0:6A:A8:BG:E5:61:E9:23:D0:F2:1E:9D:D0:6F:A4:70:0F:A9

-----> Now you have new SHA-1 KEY 
-----> With this SHA-1 KEY, Follow the Step no 4
```

**6)Now you will get NEW google map API KEY**

```
Now use this key in to Manifeast.xml file (AS SHOWN IN STEM NO 4)

<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="NEW GOOGLE MAP API KEY" />
```

**7)Now Create New APK FILE of you APLICATION with the use the existing keystore.**

It is not run when directly run from debug..You have to make every time sign apk... then after it is work

Comment: Just wondering.. why did you add here the steps for obtaining an Android Maps API v2 key when the question is related to the **v1** API?

Comment: This is indeed an irrelevant answer!

Comment: for template 8  http://pastie.org/8270603 and  template 2 use http://pastie.org/8270605